# The different meanings

Tags: sentence

> Items **believed to belong** to passengers have also been found in the water, including baby shoes, ID cards and driver's licences.

The text is from bbc news

My question here is can i used the following words instead.

1.items believed to be belonging to
2.items believed to be belonged to

I think the first 1 i can use definately but what about the second one

Comment: No, you can't use either. And there is no reason to. This is the BBC. Their English is quite alright. You should learn from them.

Comment: @RegDwigнt you're correct here but the BBC is not what it used to be; they suffer from cuts to funding for editorial staff (especially sub-editors) just like any other news organisation in the world.

Comment: Would you mind replacing your title with something that tells us a bit more about the content of your question? When reading the existing title together with other questions, I can't tell which terms your question is about. You can use the [edit] link to do this.

Answer (score 1):

"Believed to belong to..." seems the most concise and straightforward way of saying this. However, "believed to be belonging to..." is perfectly correct grammatically, it just sounds a bit odd.

In a simpler example, you could say "I give you this ring" (simple sentence) or "I am (conjugation of "to be") giving you this ring". In both these cases, when you add -ing to the end of the verb, you change it to the present participle.

"Believed to be belonged to..." doesn't make sense, as something can "be belonging" (present participle), but can't "be belonged". You could use the past participle construction - "have belonged", and say "Believed to have belonged to..." This would also imply that the items no longer belong to the passengers, which may be inaccurate.